# Stop WhatsApp Desktop App from opening on api.whatsapp.com links, run WhatsApp web instead

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-association, whatsapp, web-whatsapp

I have a personal and a business WA account. I use WhatsApp Desktop app for personal use. When I click on api.whatsapp.com links, I mean to open the web app where I can send a message from my business account. The problem is that whenever I click on these links, it shows an alert to open the desktop app and when I cancel the dialog, it does not take me to WhatsApp web and I am stuck on the page.
I have checked for defaults and protocols but WhatsApp doesn't appear there, nor are there any settings in the WhatsApp desktop app to remove such functionality.

[image]

Comment: I have the exact same question. Unfortunately I still can't find the answer. Did you?

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt https://superuser.com/questions/1634477/stop-whatsapp-desktop-app-from-opening-on-api-whatsapp-com-links-run-whatsapp-w/1775011#comment2771848_1775011

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to manually change the `api.whatsapp.com` part of the url to `web.whatsapp.com`.

So for example, you can open the URL in a new tab, then click `Cancel` on the prompt and then replace `api.` with `web.` in the URL. Then you'll get a prompt to continue the chat on *WhatsApp Web*.

Comment: This works. Replacing `api` with `web` in the url, does the trick perfectly. You can create a chrome extension for a particular Chrome browser profile for this to work always.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this will work for you. I changed this part of the web address from this:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone= ... &app_absent=0
```

to this:

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone= ... &app_absent=1
```

Answer (score 2):

I found one solution:

1. Press `Win` + `R`, type **regedit** and press OK.
2. Browse to the following location:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\whatsapp
```

3. Delete this `whatsapp` register key

This will remove the association of the whatsapp link with the app installed on the computer. Remember that Whatsapp for Windows will always create this key in the registry every time it is opened

Comment: this one got the job done!